# How do you update objects in a Parse.com database using Xamarin?

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin

I have an online Parse.com database and I can create objects and query them but not update. In the Xamarin section of the Parse.com documentation it only tells you how to update an object directly after you've created it which I don't want to do. I tried adapting what the documentation says for other platforms but it hasn't worked, I have also tried querying the database and entering the new field values directly after that but it treats them as separate functions. Does anyone have any help?

Parse.com documentation:

```
    // Create the object.
var gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore")
{
    { "score", 1337 },
    { "playerName", "Sean Plott" },
    { "cheatMode", false },
    { "skills", new List<string> { "pwnage", "flying" } },
};
await gameScore.SaveAsync();

// Now let's update it with some new data.  In this case, only cheatMode
// and score will get sent to the cloud.  playerName hasn't changed.
gameScore["cheatMode"] = true;
gameScore["score"] = 1338;
await gameScore.SaveAsync();
```

What I tried most recently:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("cust_tbl");
IEnumerable<ParseObject> customers = await query.FindAsync();
customers["user"] = admin;
record["score"] = 1338;
await record;
```

Comment: Please post code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are getting an list (IEnumerable) of objects instead of single object.  Instead, try something like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("cust_tbl");
// you need to keep track of the ObjectID assigned when you first saved,
// otherwise you will have to query by some unique field like email or username
ParseObject customer = await query.GetAsync(objectId);

customer["user"] = admin;
customer["score"] = 1338;
await customer.SaveAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Silly mistake on my part, such a help. Seriously, thank you!